# How can I search for case insensitive word in google spreadsheet using GAS?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Within a google spreadseet I can use this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\b(?i)presentation\b")
```

But in google appscript when I want to use the same Regex it doesn't work. Is there something I am missing?

```
var SHEET_NAME =  ["J3A", "J3B", "J4A"]
  var exp ="\b(?i)presentation\b"
  var regExp = new RegExp(exp)
  var searchTerm = regExp
  for (sheet in SHEET_NAME){
        var studentIdSourceLocation = search(SPREADSHEET_ID, 
        SHEET_NAME[sheet], searchTerm)

  }
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in GAS if you don't use the // notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your regex with:

`/regex here/`

as a regular variable value instead of building it as a string, and to make it globally case insensitive

`/regex here/gi`

where the `i` is insensitive and g means `globally`

you could also still just use native functions and wrap your match values with the `lower` function, and remove the `\b(i?)` nad `\b` boundaries, you dont actually need these to match them